# Connection closed, EOF detected on weblogic 12c

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic12c

I'm using the weblogic server 12c and I'm trying to access soap via an external url, I imported the necessary certificates for both the cacerts file from java 8 and the DemoTrust.jks file from weblogic.
I put the arguments in the weblogic initializer according to another question here of the forum:

> :generateClassList
>       set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Xshare:off -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+IgnoreEmptyClassPaths -XX:DumpLoadedClassList=%APPCDS_CLASS_LIST% -XX:+UseAppCDS -DUseSunHttpHandler=true -Dssl.SocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl -Dssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
>   GOTO :EOF
>
> :useArchive
>       set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -Xshare:auto -XX:+UseAppCDS -XX:+IgnoreEmptyClassPaths -XX:SharedArchiveFile=%APPCDS_ARCHIVE% -showversion -DUseSunHttpHandler=true -Dssl.SocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl -Dssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider=sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
>       set USING_SHOWVERSION=true
>   GOTO :EOF
>
> :ENDFUNCTIONS

On the console when he is reading the keystores:

```
<06/07/2017, 1:57:44,328 PM BRT> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090171> <Loading the identity certificate and private key stored under the alias DemoIdentity from the jks keystore file C:\Oracle\Middleware_12.2.1.2\user_projects\domains\base_domain\security\DemoIdentity.jks.> 
<06/07/2017, 1:57:44,332 PM BRT> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.2\wlserver\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks.> 
<06/07/2017, 1:57:44,336 PM BRT> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file C:\java\JDK18~1.0_1\jre\lib\security\cacerts.> 
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: Connection closed, EOF detected
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: Connection closed, EOF detected
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:195)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:150)
```

It happens timeout and then the eof error.
Someone to help please I'm without alternatives